# Looking to get average age between 2 linked tables

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need assistance with SQL query. I have 1 table below (see screenshot) with a list of cases and its date created. Note each case has multiple tasks attached. I am looking to calculate the age of first task created and added to the case. See screenshot 2 below for the expected output. right now if I subtract the 2 ages, it does it for each row, I am looking to do just for the oldest task on the case and calculate the overall average.

EDIT: note I am using redshift and the inital table is created after a join.

```
SELECT
t1.casecreateddate,
t1.CaseID,
t2.taskcreatedate,
t2.taskid
cast(DATEDIFF(second, t2.taskcreatedate,, t1.casecreateddate,)/86400.0 as 
decimal(6,2)) AS tasktocaseage
FROM t1
left join t2 on t2.taskid= t1.caseid
WHERE
t1.casecreateddate between '2020-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
```

[image: List of cases with tasks]

[image: looking to achieve this with SQL formula]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: thanks, i added redshift

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Redshift.  If I assume it handles common table expressions.  I worked this up with MS SQL Server in mind.  The logic should work, but you'll probably need to update some of the syntax.

```
;
with CaseTask as (
--  your query
SELECT
t1.casecreateddate,
t1.CaseID,
t2.taskcreatedate,
t2.taskid
cast(DATEDIFF(second, t2.taskcreatedate,, t1.casecreateddate,)/86400.0 as 
decimal(6,2)) AS tasktocaseage
FROM t1
left join t2 on t2.taskid= t1.caseid
WHERE
t1.casecreateddate between '2020-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
)


select CaseID
, [Min Task to Case Age]

from (
    select distinct CaseID
    , datediff(day, min(taskcreatedate) over (partition by CaseID), casecreateddate) as 'Min Task to Case Age'
    , CaseID as orderby

    from CaseTask c

    union
    select 'average' as CaseID
    , avg([Min Task to Case Age] * 1.0) as 'Min Task to Case Age'
    , 'zzzz' as orderby
    from (
        select distinct CaseID
        , datediff(day, min(taskcreatedate) over (partition by CaseID), casecreateddate) as 'Min Task to Case Age'
        from CaseTask c
    ) a
) b

order by orderby
```

Comment: hi, sorry no luck. i updated original post to include redshift note and my current sql guery to get my initial table.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
with cte as (
      select t.*
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by caseid order by task_create_date) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
      where seqnum = 1
     )
select caseid, task_to_case_age
from cte
union all
select null, avg(task_to_case_age * 1.0)
from cte;
```

Comment: I am getting "operation not supported on external tables", using redshift

Comment: @msulol . . . Interesting.  This is a **select** query and this query should run just fine on external tables.  Your question is about **select**, so this answers the question that you asked.